# laravel elequent hasmany with multiple condition

Tags: laravel

i want to get users with last messages with another user

users table

```
id 
1
2
```

messages table

```
user_id   user_reciever_id
1                2
1                2
2                1
2                1
```

i want get all users that:

```
messages.user_id=auth::id() and messages.user_reciever_id=users.id 
or
messages.user_reciever_id=auth::id() and messages.user_id=users.id
```

how to handle it with hasmany. thanks alot.

Comment: What you had tried out? Or what is your current code? Or in a model?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this =>

```
public function messages() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Messages', 'user_id' , 'id');
}

public function filteredmessages() {
    return $this->messages()->where(// condition)
                            ->where(// condition);
}

$user = User::with('filteredmessages')->get();
print_r($user);
```

Or you Can use `whereHas` like this :

```
$id = auth::id();
$user = User::whereHas('messages', function($q) use ($id){
    $q->where('user_id', $id);
    $q->where(// additional conditions)
})->get();
```

Let me know if it helps